# How I deploy my libgdx project to HTML/JS using TeaVM

Tags: gwt, libgdx, teavm, vis-runtime

I recently created a `libGDX` project using `vis-runtime version 0.3.4`. As due to long build times and requirement for separate runtime-gwt project, GWT support was dropped in 0.3.3 version of vis-runtime.

Maybe TeaVM can be used as web backend, so I am looking for integration of TeaVM with vis-runtime library ?

Take a look of this [project](https://github.com/konsoletyper/teavm-libgdx) (integration of libgdx with teaVM) that uses Maven as build system not Gradle.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I created TeaVM backend for libGDX as a prototype. I have no time to maintain it and thought someone from libGDX community becomes interested and picks this project. No one did, so backend is not maintained anymore. You can ask question on libGDX community forums and may be you find someone who is interested in developing my prototype. From my side I can help with fixing bugs in TeaVM and telling how this or that thing works in TeaVM.

Regarding Gradle, there's no official support, but 3rd party plugin is available: https://github.com/edibleday/teavm-gradle-plugin. You can examine source code and see that it's easy to write one. You can even write your own Gradle plugin if you are not satisfied with this one. However, I think that supporting Gradle is a little more complicated task than just wring Gradle plugin. For example, IDE integration is also needed (i.e. IDE must import and setup project from `build.gradle`).

Comment: Thanks for support as well as your suggestion, I will forward it to libGDX community.

Comment: Hello, @alexey-andreev perhaps you have some idea to run TeamVM JUnit test on IntelliJ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52025648/run-junit-test-with-intellij