# How can I add TeaVM to my existing libGDX project?

Tags: javascript, gwt, libgdx, kotlin, teavm

TeaVM is an alternate to GWT that compiles Java to byte code allowing for the usage of things like Scala and Kotlin, I am having a difficult time understanding the process of adding and running my libGDX project in TeaVM, I would greatly appreciate any assistance or directions on how to run the project after adding the dependencies into my build.gradle file. Thanks!

Comment: I asked [question](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=26651) on libGDX community forums, but no response yet

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42466164/how-i-deploy-my-libgdx-project-to-html-js-using-teavm

Comment: @AbhishekAryan thanks for helping point me in the right direction!, I'll look into it and post an answer if I ever figure it out!

Comment: @Yusspy perhaps you can join the Gitter group for TeaVM https://gitter.im/teavm/Lobby

Comment: See this example: https://github.com/hollingsworthd/micronaut-libgdx-teavm