# How can I compile Kotlin code to JavaScript for use in my LibGDX web application?

Tags: javascript, gradle, gwt, libgdx, kotlin

I am trying to run Kotlin code in my LibGDX project, and it works successfully in the desktop application, however as of now, kotlin is not supported in the Google Web Toolkit, which only compiles java code into JS.

The libGDX wiki mentions that it may be possible to compile kotlin code into JS using the built in Kotlin functionality, so, how would I go about compiling Kotlin code into JS for use with my GWT webapp? Is that even possible with libGDX's current structure, or should I just continue trying to implement TeaVM into my project, which supports JVM bytecode?

If TeaVM is a better solution or any knowledge is had on that, I asked another question just recently on how to implement TeaVM to LibGDX:
[How can I add TeaVM to my existing libGDX project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45108401/4581564)

I've had a lot of difficulty trying to figure this out for a while now, and any help would be greatly appreciated as I find it quite essential to my project!

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think so It's possible to convert `kotlin + LibGDX` project to JavaScript.

Converting Java code to Kotlin is not a 100% automated process so Java code can't compile to JavaScript using Kotlin2JS.<sup>[1](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/compile-java-to-javascript/2034)</sup>

`kotlin2js` is source-to-source transpiler and it knows nothing about Java and Java libraries. LibGDX is written in Java, so you can't write your libGDX game on Kotlin and transpile it to JavaScript.

Comment: So would I be better off trying to get TeaVM to work?

Comment: currently seems that [TeaVM](http://teavm.org) or [gdx-dragome](https://github.com/xpenatan/gdx-dragome-backend) is only solution, I don't have time to work on this so I'm waiting for someone start working on this issue.