# Run JUnit test with IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, teavm

I'm using IntelliJ 2018.1 and I am trying to run a [TeaVM](http://teavm.org/) JUnit test but when running the test from **CTRL + SHIFT + F10** tests are getting skipped:

```
@RunWith(TeaVMTestRunner.class)
@SkipJVM
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class ShapeTest {

    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ShapeTest.class.getName());
    @Rule
    public final ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

    @Test
    public void testGet() {
        System.out.println("ShapeTest - testGet");
        String response = Shape.get("https://httpbin.org/get")
                .header("accept", "application/json")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .asJson();

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
        String url = json.getString("url");
        JSONObject headers = json.getJSONObject("headers");
        assertNotNull(json);
        assertNotNull(url);
        assertNotNull(headers);

        System.out.println(json.toString());
    }

}
```

But when running from terminal using this command below, it works:

```
mvn test -Dteavm.junit.target=target/js-tests -Dteavm.junit.js.runner=h
tmlunit -Dteavm.junit.js.threads=2
```

Any IntelliJ/JUnit expert here that may have some idea why is this happening?

Comment: What happens when you select the class and go for "run tests" from the context menu?

Comment: `Test ignored.` this is what is shown in the log

Comment: What is skip jvm about? Beyond that, I guess this could simply be something that doesn't work in intellij. I would turn to their product forum and ask there. You often hear back from their support team within hours. Maybe not on Sundays...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the same `-D` parameters in Run configuration settings. Press "Run" (Alt+Shift+F10 on Windows, Ctrl+Alt+R on Mac), select your run configuration, Right arrow, Edit:

[image: Edit Configuration]

Then specify all `-D` parameters under VM options:

[image: VM options]

After that, the options will be passed to TeaVM Runner just like it works with `mvn test` command.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to intellij as I m. I had junits written, only wanted to run them. In eclipse, you go to test class-> ***right click -> run-> as junit***. Somewhat like this we do. Its similar in intellij too. Go to test class right click and run as junits. 
If such option is not available, then the problem might lie at
***file->project structure-> module-> source*** here your tests must not been configured to the test folder of your repo.
So, in ***project structure-> module->sources*** click on test in module and then select the path to test folder . Then apply-> ok. 
Now Run as test option will be available on right click on test class.